# Show that $f \left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) = -\sqrt[^n]{ {x}_{1} {x}_{2} \ldots {x}_{n} }$ is a convex function , for positive x

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, partial-derivative, machine-learning

I'm having trouble/mistake proving this since when I try to calculate the hessian, the partial derivatives of i,j elements are negative.

This is my current direction and I don't know how to continue:

Since $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ is a continuously differentiable function, the Hessian matrix is symmetric. Now, we can compute the diagonal and off-diagonal entries of the Hessian matrix as follows:

$$ \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{i}^{2}} = \frac{n-1}{n^{2}  x_{i}^{2n-1}} \prod_{j\neq i}^{n} x_{j}^\frac{1}{n} $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}} = - \frac{1}{n^{2}x_{i}^{\frac{n-1}{n}} x_{j}^{\frac{n-1}{n}}} \prod_{k \neq i,j}^{n} x_{k}^{\frac{1}{n}} $$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that log-convex functions are convex.

Answer (score 1):

From your last result, we have
$$ \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{i}^{2}} = \frac{n-1}{n^{2}  x_{i}^{\color{red}2}} \prod_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}^\frac{1}{n} $$
$$ \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}} = - \frac{1}{n^{2}x_{i} x_{j}} \cdot \prod_{k =1}^{n} x_{k}^{\frac{1}{n}} $$

The term $\frac{1}{n^2}\prod_{k =1}^{n} x_{k}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is positive, so, it suffices to prove: the matrix $\mathbf{M}=(m_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ defined by
$$m_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
\frac{n-1}{x_i^2} &  \text{for }i=j\\
\frac{1}{x_i x_j} &  \text{for }i\ne j\\
\end{cases}$$
is positive definite for the convexity.

For any vector $\mathbf{A} = (a_i)_{1\le i\le n}$, if we can prove that $\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{M}  \mathbf{A} \ge0$ then we can prove $\mathbf{M}$ is a positive definite matrix. Indeed, we have
$$ \begin{align}
\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{M}  \mathbf{A} &=  \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{n-1}{x_i^2}\cdot a_i^2\right) -\sum_{1\le i , j \le n}\left( \frac{1}{x_ix_j}\cdot a_ia_j\right) \\
 &=  \sum_{i=1}^n (n-1)\left(\frac{a_i}{x_i}\right)^2 -2\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}\left( \frac{x_i}{a_i}\cdot \frac{x_j}{a_j}\right) \\
&=\sum_{1\le i < j \le n} \left(\left(\frac{a_i}{x_i}\right)^2-2\frac{x_i}{a_i}\cdot \frac{x_j}{a_j} + \left(\frac{a_j}{x_j}\right)^2\right)\\
&=\sum_{1\le i < j \le n} \left(\frac{a_i}{x_i} - \frac{a_j}{x_j}\right)^2  \ge 0
 \end{align}$$

By consequence, $\mathbf{M}$ is a positive definite matrix and so is the Hessian matrix.

We can conclude that the function is convex.

Q.E.D

Comment: can you explain why the last term that you write is true?

Comment: @OrenBenEliyahu I added some intermediate steps. I hope it is clearer now?

Comment: @OrenBenEliyahu if the answer answered your question, don’t forget to « accept » by clicking to the symbol at the answer

Comment: I don't understand why the second and the third row are true, can you explain it?

Comment: @OBE The second row is just an transformation of these summands. In the third row, the $n-1$ summands $\left(\frac{a_i}{x_i}\right)^2$ are distributed to form the summand of the third row.